# Binding parent styles to it's child Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

Can I pass css styles associated wit a css class defined in parent's `templateUrls` css to child component css class ?

Something like:

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component [class.child-class]="class.parent-class"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Now I am using `/deep/` in parent's css on a css class which I have on child's `<div>` but I would like not to limit my parents css class name to something hard coded in child.

Comment: Have you considered passing class name via `@Input` of child component and using it as needed?

Comment: I thought about it but aren't styles encapsulated in component ?

Comment: yes, styles will be encapsulated if they are in components, If you have some common style which needs to be applied to both parent and child you may keep it in global style so that they are not encapsulated, and based upon some behavior in parent you can pass which class to use in child, Cheers!!

Comment: In my case the child component is a button with loading animation. I want to use it as generic button in different parts of app where it needs different styles. Whole app is styled in components. Having buttons styled in global css doesn't appeal to me 

Comment: you can add [ngClass] in parent then use nested class in child

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `
<div>stuff before</div>
<div class="wrapper>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div>stuff after</div>`,
  styles: [`
.wrapper /deep/ * {
// styles for children here
}
  `]
})
```